# Angular Universal for Website module only

Tags: angular, seo, angular6, angular-universal

I am working on a web-app built in Angular-6.

I have several feature modules. One of them is **Website** module which contains static pages of my website.

I want to use **Angular-Universal** only for **Website Module**, all other pages should work normally, without **Angular-Universal.**

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use nginx for routing requests to **Website Module** hosted by Node with Angular Universal and nginx with the angular build(other pages).

Or you can config server.ts for routing requests.

Or build **Website Module** by [prerender](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/prerender.ts) and hosted all with nginx